# Updating a 2d list

Tags: python, python-2.7

`lis` is a list.Trying to manipulate it as a 2d list and update with some 
 values.

```
lis = [0 for i in range(3)]
print "1st time list",lis

for i in range(3):
    lis[i]=[0]*2  # replaced and tried with  lis[i]=[0,0]

print "2nd time list ",lis

for i in  range(3):
    for j in lis[i]:
        print "i:",i
        print "j:",j
        lis[i][j] = i+j
        print "value entered: ", lis[i][j]   # here showing correct o/p             

print lis                   #should be [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]] , but not coming
                            #as expected.
```

Could anybody explain it and correct me?

Comment: O/p getting : 
1st list [0, 0, 0]
2nd list  [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
i: 0
j: 0
val entered:  0

i: 0
j: 0
val entered:  0

i: 1
j: 0
val entered:  1

i: 1
j: 0
val entered:  1

i: 2
j: 0
val entered:  2

i: 2
j: 0
val entered:  2

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you want to do is have every inner list contain the index number as the elements `[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2],[3,3] ...]`

Keeping with the current structure of your code, this should work:

```
lis = [0 for i in range(3)]
print "1st time list",lis

for i in range(3):
    lis[i]=[0]*2  # replaced and tried with  lis[i]=[0,0]

print "2nd time list ",lis

for i in range(len(lis)):
    lis[i] = [i, i]

print lis
```

The reason yours wasn't working is because of how you're doing the inner loop. `for j in lis[i]` doesnt do what you expect. What that line does is it takes lis[i] which is a list in itself, and loops through every element in that list. At the time of that loop, the last element is 0 so you're always getting a 0 in the final inner list position.

This is probably a simpler way to achieve what you want (although I don't know if your example is part of a larger project which requires you to do it the way you're currently doing it):

```
numElements = 3

lis = []

for i in range(numElements):
    lis.append([i,i])

print lis
```

Comment: print "value entered: ", lis[i][j] 

 #This is giving correct outputs individually , but when trying to print list as a whole showing different output. Im not getting the reason.

Comment: `print lis` should give `[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]` . What are you seeing?

Comment: using my code only getting :
#individual output is fine, but as a whole it's confusing. There's the question. why?
i: 0
j: 0
val entered:  0

i: 1
j: 0
val entered:  1

i: 1
j: 0
val entered:  1

i: 2
j: 0
val entered:  2

i: 2
j: 0
val entered:  2

[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to populate the list so it ends up with the contents you say you want:

```
lis = range(3)
print "1st time list", lis

for i in range(len(lis)):
    j = lis[i]
    lis[i] = [j, j]

print lis  # -> [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

There are shorter and faster ways to do this, but since it's uclear what you're trying to accomplish, I haven't shown them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create something like [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], ...]

I would do it so,

```
print [[i, i] for i in xrange(n)]
```

Where n is the number of such entries that you want. In your first example, n = 3

You can read more about list comprehensions https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html